# Openshift build script not setting environment variables

Tags: python, openshift

I'm attempting to deploy some app using openshift, but I need to configure a proxy to allow the cartridge to download some libraries from pip.

However, attempting to export the environment variables needed in the pre-build hook (or any other hook in action_hooks) just doesn't stick.

How can I set arbitrary environment variables in an openshift cartridge?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the rhc env set command to set them

```
corey-redhat:.openshift cdaley$ rhc env --help
Usage: rhc env <action>

Manages the user-defined environment variables set on a given application. To see a list of all
environment variables use the command 'rhc list-env <application>'. Note that some predefined
cartridge-level environment variables can also be overriden, but most variables provided by gears
are read-only.

Type 'rhc set-env --help' for more details.

List of Actions
  list          List all environment variables set on the application
  set           Set one or more environment variable(s) to your application
  show          Show the value of one or more environment variable(s) currently set to your
                application
  unset         Remove one or more environment variable(s) currently set to your application
```